# how to solve mysql define error in vb.net app?

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

i have this piece of code

```
 Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO person(name) VALUES (@name);"
 Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(name.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name.Text) Then
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", " ")
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.Text)
        End If
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
```

when i run the code i get this exception:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Fatal error encountered during command execution. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Parameter '@name' must be defined.
```

how to solve?

Comment: try simply with cmd.Parameters.Add()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved just adding this to connection string:

```
Allow User Variables=True
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO person(name) VALUES (@name);"
 Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand()
         cmd.CommandText = query;
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(name.Text) Or String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name.Text) Then
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", " ")
        Else
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.Text)
        End If

        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As MySqlException
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
End Try
```